# Recurrence formula for digamma function with rational number

Tags: gamma-function

It is well known that $\psi\left(  x+N\right)  =\psi\left(  x\right)  +\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\frac{1}{x+k}$.

Is there a recurrence formula for $\psi\left(  x+\frac{p}{q}\right)  $ where $\frac{p}{q}$ is rational number

Comment: I guess you had a look at the wikipedia page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Gaussian_sum. There are some nice formulas, but maybe not quite what you're looking for.

Comment: Your first formula comes from $\Gamma(x+1)=x\Gamma(x)$.  So maybe your question is related to whether there is a formula $\Gamma(x+1/q) = \dots$.